# Prove that morphisms into initial objects are isomorphisms

Tags: category-theory

Suppose the following takes place in the category of sets.

Let $f:X \rightarrow 0$ be any morphism into the initial object. I want to prove that the unique ${!}:0 \rightarrow X$ is an inverse to $f$. That $f {!} =id$ is clear since $0$ is initial, but the other way i can't see what to do other than use the fact that the category has exponentials.

Solution (possible):

Since the unique arrow $0 \to X$ corresponds to any $X \times 0 \to X$ which correspond to $0 \to X^X$ of which there is only one, the constant map sending everything to the identity. Hence, ${!} \circ f = id$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It generalizes to cartesian closed categories. You want to show that in such a category, if there is an arrow $X\to 0$, then $X\simeq 0$.

So assume you have  such an arrow and consider the arrow $g: X\to X\times 0$ that you get from it and $id_X$, and $pr$ the projection $X\times 0\to X$. Then $g\circ pr : X\times 0 \to X\times 0$, and so as $X\times 0$ is initial in a ccc (I think I've shown this in another post), $g\circ pr = id_{X\times 0}$. Moreover by definition of $g$, $pr\circ g = id_X$.
Thus $X\simeq X\times 0 \simeq 0$, $X$ is initial and that works.

(I advise you to draw the diagrams to see it clearly)

If you want another proof that $X\times 0$ is initial in a cartesian closed category, let me know (that's where you use the exponentials)

Answer (score 5):

It is not true in an arbitrary category. For example, in the category of sets and *partial* functions, the empty set is an initial object -- but the everywhere undefined function $X\to\varnothing$ is not an isomorphism unless $X$ is itself empty.

Therefore you **have** to use something that is specific to $\mathbf{Set}$ here. And then you might as well be concrete and admit that $\varnothing$ is the only initial object, and the only map *into* $\varnothing$ is the empty function $\varnothing\to\varnothing$, and that *happens to be* an isomorphism.

Comment: It seems worth pointing out that the category you give in your example in the first paragraph is equivalent to the category of pointed sets.

Comment: I use sets with total functions, not partial ones.

Comment: @Bartuc: That much is clear. But this doesn't change the fact that _there are categories where your property is not true_, so you have no hope of proving it for _your_ category by purely category-theoretic reasoning. And since you _have_ to go beyond category theory somehow and find something _that is true for your category and false for mine_ you can just as well admit that _looking at the actual sets_ what you want to prove is obviously true.

Comment: Okay, but I am using the ETCS axioms and not the ZFC axioms, if that is what you mean. I know that $0$ is empty, I just wanted a more neat way to show it, other than writing it in the usual ZFC notation, if that makes sense.

Comment: Took a look at this problem, in the Set category, there shouldn't be any morphisms going into empty set as it implies proving false using non false. So there is only one single morphism going into empty, which makes OP's claim consistent in this category, doesn't it? I don't find your example denies the claim.

Comment: Indeed, this requires a monomophism, as shown in Barr-Wells 2.8.7...